# Why am I getting a Sending failed Error in AMFPHP/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml, amfphp

I am using remote object in flex to call a method in amfphp. I have project setup properly with a services-config.xml in d src, d end point uri pointing to the gateway.php. After testing on my localhost everything works fine but when I copied my files to a remote server repoint the uri in d servies-config and then recompiling the application gives a sending failed error. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of an error or warning on server side. php send's back to you that message, and amfphp don't know how cast it to amf format. so the problem is in your server side, that's for sure

one more thing, use zendamf, instead of amfphp, it's done by same developer and you don't need to install entire zend framework, only zendamf lib, it's small and doest the job perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

download and install [charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) - helps you debug your application and get the exact error message from the server.